# How to set the value of a specific element of parameter array

Tags: ros2, parameters

Does anybody know how to set the value of a specific element of a parameter array without having to reset the whole array ?
For instance modifying just the x linear max_velocity of the velocity smoother without touching the y linear and z angular max_velocity
The following sets all:
`ros2 param set /velocity_smoother max_velocity "[0.5, 0.0, 0.08]"`
I don't believe there is a solution without reading first the existing array, but maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe so, they're taken in whole. Perhaps an option would be to use the parameter client to get the current parameter setting, then take that structure, make your change, and submit the change back to that server. That way, the others you know won't change, whatever they were.

A little less direct than changing just one value, but should get you what you need in a generic way.